# what is annotations and checking args?

Tags: python

I want to write program that check args. Do annotations are use for this purpose?
actually what dose annotations  do ?

```
def bar(x: str ) -> int:
    return 12.5
```

but I can put a int to x and return a float!! so what annotations do ?

```
>>> bar(12)
12.5
>>>
```

I know for checking arg I can use :

#### style1:

```
def foo(x: str ):
if type(x)==str:
    return 0
else :return (-1)
```

to do this by annotations :

```
def foo(string : str) -> str:
    if foo.__annotations__.get('string')==type(string):
        print('continue...')
```

that mean annotations does not force args ?! so why do not use style1 ?
actually I want to know that annotations do in simple terms ?

Comment: They annotate? Possible duplicate of [What are good uses for Python3's "Function Annotations"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038033/what-are-good-uses-for-python3s-function-annotations) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784713/what-good-are-python-function-annotations?lq=1

Comment: Read the PEP:  https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/.  Also useful is https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/