# Why is the name of the containing class not recognized as a return value function annotation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, type-hinting

I was going to use [Python function annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3038033/1106367) to specify the type of the return value of a static factory method. I understand this is [one of the desired use cases](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/#fundamentals-of-function-annotations) for annotations.

```
class Trie:
    @staticmethod
    def from_mapping(mapping) -> Trie:
        # docstrings and initialization ommitted
        trie = Trie()
        return trie
```

[PEP 3107](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) states that:

> Function annotations are nothing more than a way of associating arbitrary Python expressions with various parts of a function at compile-time.

`Trie` is a valid expression in Python, isn't it? Python doesn't agree or rather, can't find the name:

> `def from_mapping(mapping) -> Trie:`
>    `NameError: name 'Trie' is not defined`

It's worth noting that this error does not happen if a fundamental type (such as `object` or `int`) or a standard library type (such as `collections.deque`) is specified.

**What is causing this error and how can I fix it?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PEP 484 provides an official solution to this in the form of [forward references](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references).

> When a type hint contains names that have not been defined yet, that definition may be expressed as a string literal, to be resolved later.

In the case of the question code:

```
class Trie:
    @staticmethod
    def from_mapping(mapping) -> Trie:
        # docstrings and initialization ommitted
        trie = Trie()
        return trie
```

Becomes:

```
class Trie:
    @staticmethod
    def from_mapping(mapping) -> 'Trie':
        # docstrings and initialization ommitted
        trie = Trie()
        return trie
```

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised I missed that -- thank you for contributing this answer.

Answer (score 12):

`Trie` is a valid expression, and evaluates to the current value associated with the name name `Trie`. But that name is not defined yet -- a class object is only bound to its name *after* the class body has run to completition. You'll note the same behavior in this much simpler example:

```
class C:
    myself = C
    # or even just
    C
```

Normally, the workaround would be setting the class attribute after the class has been defined, outside the class body. This is not a really good option here, though it works. Alternatively, you could use any placeholder value in the initial definition, then replace it in the `__annotations__` (which is legal because it's a regular dictionary):

```
class C:
    def f() -> ...: pass
print(C.f.__annotations__)
C.f.__annotations__['return'] = C
print(C.f.__annotations__)
```

It *does* feel rather hacky though. Depending on your use case, it might be possible to instead use a sentinel object (e.g. `CONTAINING_CLASS = object()`) and leave interpreting that to whatever actually processes the annotations.

Comment: Interesting... however, I can use the class name *inside* my static method. Is this because the contents of a function are only parsed when it is executed, but the signature is parsed immediately after the class definition? Here's [the relevant part](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions) of the Python language reference for anyone else interested.

Comment: @codesparkle: Parsing is separate from execution. The error happens on execution. Your class definition, including annotations is an execution of the code. However, the innards of the functions are not executed (obviously) when the class is defined.

Comment: How about just writing `-> 'returns Trie'`

Comment: @jamylak Depending on the use case, that's possible. However, there are many use cases where it's less useful or even awful (namely anything where one wants a program to figure out which type you're talking about). Honestly, for that textual description I'd just use a docstring.