# Pycharm: type annotation of factory method doesn't provide autocomplete

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm, type-annotation

I'm trying to write out type annotation for proper autocomplete in PyCharm. See this refined code example:

```
class TestClass:
    a = 1

    @staticmethod
    def make_new_with_a(a: int) -> TestClass:
        t = TestClass()
        t.a = a
        return t

print(TestClass.make_new_with_a(7).a)
```

Code works and prints `7` to output. But PyCharm underlines `-> TestClass` with red and shows `Unresolved reference 'TestClass'` on mouse over hint. Autocompletion for fields of method return type (`...make_new_with_a(7).` + `<ctrl+space>`) doesn't work.

Similar questions:

- [putting current class as return type annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853469/python-put-current-class-as-return-type-annotation)
- [Why is the name of the containing class not recognized as a return value function annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741887/why-is-the-name-of-the-containing-class-not-recognized-as-a-return-value-functio)

Comment: check it with python3.5 and pycharm 5.0 rc, should work

Comment: The solution is given in the linked _Similar questions_: put `-> 'TestClass'` (as a string) instead `-> TestClass`. PyCharm/IntelliJ IDEA recognises this and gives you autocompletion and all them goodies. ([Type Hints: forward references](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references))

Comment: Oh wow that really blows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [putting current class as return type annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853469/putting-current-class-as-return-type-annotation)