# What does -> do in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I saw a python example today and it used -> for example this was what I saw:

```
spam = None
bacon = 42
def monty_python(a:spam,b:bacon) -> "different:":
    pass
```

What is that code doing? I'm not quite sure I've never seen code like that I don't really get what

```
 a:spam,b:bacon
```

is doing either, can someone explain this for me? I googled, "what does -> do in python" but no good searches came up that I found.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is function annotation for a return type. [`annotations`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038033/what-are-good-uses-for-python3s-function-annotations) do nothing inside the code, they are there to help a user with code completion (in my experience).

Here is the [PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) for it.

Let me demonstrate, what I mean by "annotations do nothing inside the code". Here is an example:

```
def fun(a: str, b: int) -> str:
    return 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(fun(10, 10))
```

The above code will run without any errors. but as you can see the first parameter *should* be a `string`, and the second an `int`. But, this only is a problem in my IDE, the code runs just fine:

[image]

Comment: Oh I see that is interesting thanks for clearing that up for me, and by the way what editor are you using?

Comment: PyCharm 3.0 from Jetbrains. But this kind of functionality is available in other IDEs too. You can try PyCharm for free. PyDev also offers this, I think.

Comment: What's your IDE? Very nice!

Comment: Look above at my previous comment :)

Comment: Nice, I did not know you could do that in python. I guest python is becoming more and more object oriented.

Answer (score 7):

They're [function annotations](http://ceronman.com/2013/03/12/a-powerful-unused-feature-of-python-function-annotations/). They don't really do anything by themselves, but they can be used for documentation or in combination with metaprogramming.

Comment: Just to make it clear, these are only available in Python3, not in python 2!