# Python functions annotation vs documentation

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python3 has an annotation feature. Should I use it instead documentations string?
I. e. what is the right way:

```
def func(points: [{'x': int, 'y': int}]): -> int
    pass
```

vs

```
def func(points):
    ''' Take a list of dicts, dict present a point, and contain keys:
    'x' - int, x position
    'y' - int, y position
    Return int

    '''
    pass
```

Comment: There's no hard and fast rule. There's good libraries out there that will happily use doc strings/functions to generate docs (eg: Sphinx) but if you're using them for documentation, you can't really use them for other stuff such as constraint checking... It's mostly just a case of, if you're going to use them, pick how you're going to use them and be consistent. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038033/what-are-good-uses-for-python3s-function-annotations for other uses...

Comment: Why don't you use both?

Comment: Sometimes a lot of documentations is excess. So annotations - way to shorten comments, I think.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are an addition to docstrings. From the official function annotations [pep](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/):

```
Because Python's 2.x series lacks a standard way of annotating a function's
parameters and return values, a variety of tools and libraries have appeared to
fill this gap.
```

But the Python community likes standartizing things (ref. `PEP`s). So they came up with the function annotations, which are primarily targeted at third-party libraries and tools - IDEs, code quality / static analysis tools and etc. As the `PEP` says itself:

```
By itself, Python does not attach any particular meaning or significance to
annotations.(...)meaning comes from third-party libraries alone.
```

**Edit**: A really good article about uses of annotations (early error detection, code completion and tooling support in general) can be found [here](http://ceronman.com/2013/03/12/a-powerful-unused-feature-of-python-function-annotations/).