# What type of declaration is `def m_test(x: my_var) -> list:`

Tags: python, python-3.x

I saw a type of method declaration in a question, then I searched hundred times! but I could find any useful information, here is declaration:

```
my_var = "556"
def my_meth(x: my_var) -> list:
    #doSomthing
```

I found by this type I can pass a copy of global `my_var` to `my_meth` by default. (It means `my_meth` only needs one argument that passes to `x`) 
Can you describe this type of declaration?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038033/what-are-good-uses-for-python3s-function-annotations?rq=1

Comment: Thanks but I didn't know that is the name of this type declaration :)

Comment: Even I didn't know :) So only showed you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called function annotations. You can read more about them here http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/

```
 -> list:
```

means that the `my_meth` function returns a `list`

```
x: my_var
```

has no meaning here. The string after the `:` serves as the description of the particular parameter.

```
x: An integer value
```

would have been more meaningful.