# Python 3.5 type hinting does not result in an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

One of the [new features](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html) in Python 3.5 is type-hinting, inspired by [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/).

> typing: [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) – Type Hints.

I want to test it, but it does not work as expected.

```
import typing

class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, initial_balance: int = 0) -> None:
        self.balance = initial_balance
    def deposit(self, amount: int) -> None:
        self.balance += amount
    def withdraw(self, amount: int) -> None:
        self.balance -= amount
    def overdrawn(self) -> bool:
        return str(self.balance < 0)

my_account = BankAccount(15)
my_account.withdraw(5)
print(type(my_account.overdrawn()))
```

*results in:*

```
<class 'str'>
```

I would have expected an error, as I am expecting a `bool` as the return type. I tested it on Python 3.5 (docker) and local. Did I miss something, to make it work? Does this typing not work at runtime?

Comment: "*no type checking happens at runtime.*" It's right in the first section.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See the fifth paragraph of the abstract in the PEP you link to:

> While these annotations are available at runtime through the usual `__annotations__` attribute, *no type checking happens at runtime* . Instead, the proposal assumes the existence of a separate off-line type checker which users can run over their source code voluntarily

Answer (score 6):

In order to get `static` checks, consider a project like [`mypy`](http://mypy-lang.org/), on which PEP 484 was based on.

**No checking will be performed on runtime** is ***explicitly*** declared in the PEP to ease fears of some transition to a static looking Python.

---

As Daniel pointed out, you can view the attributes in the [`__annotations__`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) attribute in a form of:

```
{'return': bool}
```

for function `overdrawn()`.

If you want you can create your own small type checking function to perform little runtime checks utilizing this `dict`. Play around with it. Additionally, if you're up for the read, take a look at my answer on type hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5/32558710#32558710).