# Meaning of a function "-> str"

Tags: python

```
def f(ham: str, eggs: str = 'eggs') -> str:
    print("Annotations:", f.__annotations__)
    print("Arguments:", ham, eggs)
    return ham + ' and ' + eggs
```

In the above block of code which got from **https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#documentation-strings**

My question is about the `-> str` in the above block of code. What does it do ?

Comment: But.. that link *explicitly explains* what it does. You have quite literally linked to the canonical documentation for that syntax.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  `def f(ham: str, eggs: str = 'eggs')` in this block they did mention **str**, so why did they again have to mark/say the same at the last?

Comment: Because the `str` in that block has to do with the types of the variables getting passed in, not the one getting returned.

Comment: @DanielRoseman is right, your link also references [PEP 0484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#abstract) which goes into greater detail about this.

Comment: [PEP 0484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) is probably all you want to know about the current state of type hints / function annotations.

Comment: @h4kr minor 7 year later heads up - that function and the documentation you're looking for is actually pulled from https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#function-annotations, not the doc strings section.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It specifies the return value. It has nothing to do with the code at all and is just for documentation purposes.

Answer (score 4):

Those are type hints. Various type checkers can use them to determine if you're using the correct types. In your example, you function is expecting `ham` of type `str`, and `eggs` of type `str` (defaulting to `eggs`). The final `-> str` implies that this function, should have a return type of `str` as well.

For more information see:

- [What are Type hints in Python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5)
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/

Comment: What if I do not return it as a string?

Comment: Your code won't be affected - it would still run, but if you ran your code through a type checker, such as [mypy](http://mypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basics.html#type-checking-and-running-programs), you would get a warning.

Comment: `What if I do not return it as a string?` Try it and see. It depends on the context. Python will not type check the return if that is what you are asking.

Comment: And as @dawg mentioned - the best way to learn about these things is to try them out for yourself - bring up a shell, create a function that has that annotation (or copy it from the example) and try running it.