# Set IntelliJ/Pycharm to handle pandas "Unresolved references" warning

Tags: python, pandas, intellij-idea, pycharm, suppress-warnings

Whenever I try to access a non-method attribute of a Series or DataFrame (such as `columns` or `loc`), IntelliJ throws me an "unresolved reference" warning which doesn't crash my code, but is fairly annoying to see. I'd rather not disable this inspection, and I'd like to avoid peppering my code with suppressions.

I've set the "Collect run-time types information for code insight" option of the debugger, but this didn't work. I've also tried adding references to ignore in the "Ignore References" list in the Inspections tab, but nothing I tried seemed to work.

The warning I get will be something like `Cannot find reference loc in 'Series | Series'`.

Comment: Just noticed this after copying code that runs 100% correctly in jupyter notebook, to PyCharm. This is still an outstanding occurrence from over a year ago..

Comment: Can you provide the exact version of IntelliJ/Pycharm you are using and some sample code?

Comment: Works for me https://i.imgur.com/0c70966.png no changes to default inspections.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that works for me when PyCharm's autocomplete is having trouble figuring out my variable type is type hinting. It happens rarely enough that I (thankfully) don't have to do it that often.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()  # type: pd.DataFrame
```

More info on typing can be found here: [What are Type hints in Python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5)