# Python Type Hinting - Method Returns a List of the Current Class

Tags: python, types

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class CareerTransition(object):
    def __init__(self, title_from: str, title_to: str)->None:
        self.title_from = title_from    # type: str
        self.title_to = title_to        # type: str

    @staticmethod
    def from_file(fname: str, verbose : bool = False)->List[CareerTransition]:
        #Do some stuff
        pass
```

I get this error when I try to instantiate that class:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/simon.hughes/GitHub/analytics-py-careerpathing/careerpathing/data/employment_history.py", line 8, in <module>
    class CareerTransition(object):
  File "/Users/simon.hughes/GitHub/analytics-py-careerpathing/careerpathing/data/employment_history.py", line 17, in CareerTransition
    def from_file(fname: str, verbose : bool = False)->List[CareerTransition]:
NameError: name 'CareerTransition' is not defined
```

Is it not possible to use type annotations to refer to generic types that reference the current class? To clarify (as it may not be obvious) it's throwing that error as the class is not defined yet. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I have had a number of people tell me that python doesn't do type hinting (only to delete their comments). To save you time - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5

Comment: I have also had people tell me that's not how you type a list, it is if you are specifying a generic list as a type hint - see here: http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/11/python-3-5-type-hinting-in-pycharm-5/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An even nicer way then writing the concrete class as stated by @chepner is to use the literal `__class__`. The whole thing would look like this:

```
@staticmethod
def from_file(fname: str, verbose : bool = False) -> List['__class__']:
    # Do some stuff
    pass
```

Comment: That's a literal string, not the literal `__class__`. FWIW, literal `__class__` appears to work in Py3.8

Answer (score 15):

Use a string literal for a forward reference:

```
@staticmethod
def from_file(fname: str, verbose : bool = False)->List['CareerTransition']:
    #Do some stuff
    pass
```

Comment: brilliant. You woudln't believe how many people tried to tell me python doesn't support type hints or that I was typing List incorrectly (list).

Comment: @Simon A total of two people said that. :)

Comment: Ok true. That's still people :)

Comment: People are still people! :) We can agree on that :)