# DataType of Arguments for Function in Python

Tags: python, function, filter, arguments

Here's a thing
I want to predefine DataType of any argument accepts by a Function in python just like we do in C or C++.

```
# For Example
def maw(x, y):
  return x+y # I want to predefine this x and y to be integer-type
```

Just like

```
// This is C-Program which accepts only integer as a parameter
int main(int x, int y){
return x+y;
}
```

I don't want to Filter this parameter with another line of code like

```
if 'int' in type(x):
  pass
else:
  return False
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explicitly Define Datatype in Python Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43233535/explicitly-define-datatype-in-python-function)

Comment: something like `assert(isinstance(x, int) and isinstance(y, int))` ?

Comment: type annotation won't raise error they are just for convenience

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to declare variables in Python, since neither "declaration" nor "variables" in the C sense exist.

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933197/how-to-declare-variable-type-c-style-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Type annotation is still only a convenience, unfortunately, though it'd be nice to mandatory enable them by a Python interpreter flag.

However, they can be used for a static analysis with [mypy](https://pypi.org/project/mypy/) or for a dynamic, runtime analysis (quite efficient for running in combination with unittesting) with [ensure](https://pypi.org/project/ensure/).

Taken from `ensure`'s doc:

```
from ensure import ensure_annotations

@ensure_annotations
def f(x: int, y: float) -> float:
    return x + y
```

or in your DateType case:

```
>>> from ensure import ensure_annotations
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> @ensure_annotations
... def myfunc(param: datetime) -> datetime:
...     return 123
... 
>>> @ensure_annotations
... def mycorrectfunc(param: datetime) -> datetime:
...     return param + timedelta(days=1)
... 
>>> myfunc(datetime.now())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../lib/python3.8/site-packages/ensure/main.py", line 855, in __call__
    raise EnsureError(msg.format(
ensure.main.EnsureError: Return value of <function myfunc at 0x7f28325d7310> of type <class 'int'> does not match annotation type <class 'datetime.datetime'>
>>> mycorrectfunc(datetime.now())
datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 15, 10, 53, 37, 888834)
>>>
```

and this is applicable for all other classes or [type aliases](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) (very!) roughly in a similar way `typedef` or rather `assert isinstance(...)` are used.