# python code simplification and explanation

Tags: python

I'm learning spark with python, I came up with this method,

```
def convert_to_row(d: dict) -> Row:
    return Row(**OrderedDict(sorted(d.items())))
```

this method takes a line and convert into `Row`.

can someone simplifies this what are these points mean.

1) `d: dict`

2) `-> Row`

3) why is `**` there? for `kvargs`?

also, if I wrap this into the class, first argument will be `self`, something like that.

```
def convert_to_row(self, d: dict) -> Row:
    return Row(**OrderedDict(sorted(d.items())))
```

will it work the same way as it was doing before?

thanks.

Comment: Related: [What are Type hints in Python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32557920/1639625) And yes, those `**` are for `kwargs` unpacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) and 2) are type hints, which:

- help other developers to understand what are the expected types of parameters/variables and what is the return type of functions
- can be checked by [*mypy*](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), a static type checker for Python

3) `**` allows you to unpack each pair of key/value from the `OrderedDict`

Finally, wrapping this function into a class by just adding `self` will work.