# Correct Type annotation for __init__

Tags: python, python-2.7, typing

What is the correct type annotation for a `__init__` function in python?

```
class MyClass:
    ...
```

Which of the following would make more sense?

```
def __init__(self):
    # type: (None) -> None

def __init__(self):
    # type: (MyClass) -> MyClass

def __init__(self):
    # type: (None) -> MyClass
```

Since we would normally instantiate as `myclass = MyClass()`, but the `__init__` function itself has no return value.

Comment: For my own curiosity, is this even necessary/expected?

Comment: @roganjosh No, it is a supported feature. I'm finding it useful as it helps my IDE(pycharm) detect type mismatches. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5

Comment: But you've tagged this as 2.7 which doesn't even support type hinting. My question was broader though, that I'm not sure it's useful for `__init__()`.

Comment: @roganjosh, you are right, it is not useful in this example. However, I would generally extend it to other `__init__` functions taking in variables. I can use some functionalities through installing typing and pycharm on 2.7.

Comment: @roganjosh Python 2 does indeed support type hinting, see [mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python2.html) I think typing should be added wherever possible, especially for things like `__init__` and things like callable classes.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

`self` should be omitted from the annotation when it is given as a comment, and `__init__()` should be marked as `-> None`. This is all specified explicitly in [PEP-0484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/).

Comment: PEP 484 says that the *return type* should be annotated as `-> None`, not that `self` should be omitted.

Comment: Indeed the rule is not explicitly stated. But examples are given [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#suggested-syntax-for-python-2-7-and-straddling-code) that omit `self`

Comment: Those examples show Python 3 code using `self` in the method signature and `-> None` as return type which is what you should do. If you want Python 2 compatibility you can put the type signature into a comment instead, and in that case you would leave out `self` in the commented type signature. You certainly wouldn't leave out `self` in the method parameters, or you are going to get parameter count-mismatch errors because the first parameter will then take the place of self. Whatever you label it doesn't matter, it's just `self` by convention. You probably meant that but wasn't clear.

Comment: Yes, leave it out of the signature, *not* the argument list :) that is what I meant. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Could you please clarify that with "`self` should be ommitted." you in fact mean not to omit the `self` parameter, but to omit the type hint for `self`?

Comment: By the way, `mypy` allows omitting ` -> None` from `__init__` – although heavily discussed – because of the reason that `__init__` can only have this return type (for type checking  ` -> None` is automatically appendend), see https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/604

Comment: You shouldn't define self type because you can call some function from an inherited class.

Comment: @LucasVazquez the inherited class is not a problem, it would be a subclass and therefore match your annotation. A sibling in the MRO would be more problematic.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using Python 3 (I hope you do), **no need to annotate `__init__` method at all since mypy 0.641 release if there's at least one annotated argument**, it must always be `None`, because it returns nothing. In other cases, mypy will raise an error. This behavior annoyed people for years but eventually it was fixed.

This is what Guido [says](http://mypy-lang.blogspot.com/2018/10/mypy-0640-released.html):

> New Feature: Allow Omitting Return Type for `__init__` It is now
> possible to omit the return type of an annotated `__init__` method
> without getting an error message. For example:
>
> ```
> class Circuit:
>     def __init__(self, voltage: float):
>         self.voltage = voltage
> ```
>
> In previous mypy versions this would elicit an error message:
>
> ```
> error: The return type of "__init__" must be None
> ```
>
> This error was just annoying as the only legal return declaration for
> `__init__` is -> None, so we’ve removed it. Note that this only works if there’s at least one annotated argument! For `__init__` methods without
> arguments you must still add -> None, otherwise the method will be
> treated as untyped, and its body will not be type checked at all.
> Examples:
>
> ```
> class UntypedExample:
>     # This method is not type-checked at all!
>     def __init__(self):
>         self.voltage = 0.0
>
> class TypedExample:
>     # This is how to ensure that a 0-argument __init__ is type-checked:
>     def __init__(self) -> None:
>         self.voltage = 0.0
> ```

Related discussions:

1. [Allow `__init__` with signature but no return type](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/604)
2. [Function is missing type annotation for `__init__`(self)](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/604)