# How to add "-> None:" to the end of __init__ functions with Notepad++?

Tags: python, regex, notepad++

I want to select every `__init__` function and add `-> None` to the end if it does not already exist. For example:

```
def __init__(self) -> None:

def __init__(self):

def __init__(self, var1, var2):

def __init__(self, var1, var2) -> None:

def __init__(self, 
    var1= 5, 
    var2: int = 4
    var3 = None
    ):

def (self, 
    var1= 5, 
    var2= 4) -> None:
```

I've figured out that `(def __init__\((.*?))(:)` seems to select the right lines, but I can't figure out how to make it ignore lines/groups of lines that contain: `-> None`.

Comment: I read here that even though it's implied, it's still recommended by PEP-0484: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46779046/correct-type-annotation-for-init

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```js
^(\h*def\h+__init__\([^()]*\)):
```

Replace with `$1 -> None:`.

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `(\h*def\h+__init__\(.*?\))` - Group 1:

  - `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
  - `def` - `def` string
  - `\h+` - 1+ horizontal whitespaces
  - `__init__` - an `__init__` string
  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `[^()]*` - any 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
  - `\)` - a `)` char.
- `:` - a colon.

Comment: I just tested and it works only if everything is on the same line. If I check "matches newline", it seems to select way to much.

Comment: @ProGamerGov I updated the answer, now, you do not have to use *`.` matches newline* with `^(\h*def\h+__init__\([^()]*\)):`.