# How could I check if an addition of two variables are same type in Python?

Tags: python, typeerror

For below program, How could I detect the variable TypeError previously other than truly running it? Does Pylint or pyflake8 has this feature?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

A = 1
B = 'b'
print(A+B)
```

Comment: `TypeError` is an exception that occurs at runtime.

Comment: google 'python type hints'. this is the relevant [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) and a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5 . also have a look at http://mypy-lang.org/ .

Answer (score 2):

You can use either **[type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type)** or [**isinstance**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) method

```
>>> type(1)
<type 'int'>
>>>

>>> isinstance(1, int)
True
>>>
```

Comment: how do you get that without 'running it'?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I think he means without actually throwing the `TypeError`

Comment: @hiroprotagonist What is the use of code if you don't run it?

Comment: Well, to cover all the "bases" (heheh), I'd recommend doing a type check against `numbers.Rational`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ or even [`numbers.Number`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/numbers.html).

Comment: @Code-Apprentice well... type checking. as statically typed languages do.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I avoided mentioning `Number` because it includes complex numbers too, though now I wonder why I didn't mention it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

`TypeError` is an exception that occurs at runtime. To avoid the exception, you can use `type()` or `isinstance()`. Although, if you find yourself doing this frequently, then you should rethink your code design.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Oops...should have googled to verify.