# Colon on left hand side of assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

For the following code, what is the colon (:) means?

```
import pandas as pd
merge: pd.DataFrame = pd.concat([train, dftt, test])
submission: pd.DataFrame = test[['test_id']]
```

Comment: A type hint... you're hinting that `merge` should reference a DataFrame object.

Comment: This is [PEP-526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/).

Comment: Not that I would know, what type hint means. But since I looked it up, I leave [this SO thread as a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32558710/8881141).