# In Python, how to I get an extended class element to show up in autocomplete?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm new to classes so using an example I found online to add some custom logging levels.  This will be contained in a library which will be importrd into various scripts.  It is working as expected but the added levels don't show up in the autocomplete list (using PyCharm) and PyCharm complains of an unresolved attribute reference in LOGGER.  When I'm coding and enter 'LOGGER.' I see the normal error, warning, info, etc. to choose from but my custom level 'verbose' is not in the list.  There will be more custom levels added as time go by and this will also be rolled out to a team of developers so I need to have this working.

Any idea why verbose is not an option in my autocomplete list?

[image]
[image]

Here are my files.

px_logger.py

```
from logging import getLoggerClass, addLevelName, setLoggerClass, NOTSET

public class PxLogger(getLoggerClass()):
    def __init__(self, name, level=NOTSET):
        super(PxLogger, self).__init__(name, level)

        addLevelName(5, "VERBOSE")

    def verbose(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        """Custom logger level - verbose"""
        if self.isEnabledFor(5):
            self._log(5, msg, args, **kwargs)
```

my_script.py

```
import json
import logging.config
from px_logger import PxLogger

logging.setLoggerClass(PxLogger)
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

with open('../logging.json') as f:  # load logging config file
    CONFIG_DICT = json.load(f)
logging.config.dictConfig(CONFIG_DICT)

LOGGER.verbose('Test verbose message')
```

Screen output

```
VERBOSE - Test verbose message
```

Comment: Are you sure about `public` in `public class PxLogger`?

Comment: What's that `public class` thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PyCharm offers various ways to accomplish [type hinting](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html)

Internally, it uses [Typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed) to determine the types of standard lib objects and common 3rd party packages.
That's also where PyCharm takes the type of the return value for [logging.getLogger](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/2and3/logging/__init__.pyi#L282) from and that's why it does not show your subclass' `verbose` method in autocomplete, because it assumes `LOGGER` to be an instance of `logging.Logger`.

The easiest way to tell PyCharm's type checker that `LOGGER` is an instance of `PxLogger` would be a type annotation in the code during assignment. **This works in Python 3.5+ only**:

```
LOGGER: PxLogger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

If you went one step further, you would encapsulate the definition of your custom logger class, it being assigned as global logger class and the definition of a wrapper for `logging.getLogger` inside your module.

This would enable your coworkers to just import your module instead of `logging` and use it just as they would with the original `logging` without having to worry about which class to set as logger class or how to annotate the variable that holds their logger.

There's three options to include type hinting for the type checker when going down this road.

**px_logger.py**

```
# basically, import from logging whatever you may need and overwrite where necessary
from logging import getLogger as _getLogger, Logger, addLevelName, setLoggerClass, NOTSET
from typing import Optional # this only for the Python 3.5+ solution

class PxLogger(Logger):  # Note: subclass logging.Logger explicitly
    def __init__(self, name, level=NOTSET):
        super(PxLogger, self).__init__(name, level)

        addLevelName(5, "VERBOSE")

    def verbose(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        """Custom logger level - verbose"""
        if self.isEnabledFor(5):
            self._log(5, msg, args, **kwargs)

setLoggerClass(PxLogger)

"""
Possible approaches, implement one of the below.
The first is Python 3.5+ only.
The second and third work for both, Python 2 and Python 3.
"""
# using type annotation syntax (py35+)
def getLogger(name: Optional[str]=None) -> PxLogger:
    _logr: PxLogger = _getLogger(name)
    return _logr

# using (legacy) docstring syntax (py2and3)
def getLogger(name=None)
    """
    :param name: str
    :rtype: PxLogger
    """ 
    return _getLogger(name)

# using a stub file (py2and3)
def getLogger(name=None):
    return _getLogger(name)
```

The Python 2and3 stub file approach requires a file named `py_logger.pyi` next to the actual module file `px_logger.py` in your package.

**px_logger.pyi**

```
# The PEP-484 syntax does not matter here. 
# The Python interpreter will ignore this file, 
# it is only relevant for the static type checker
import logging

class PxLogger(logging.Logger):
    def verbose(self, msg, *args, **kwargs) -> None: ...

def getLogger(name) -> PxLogger: ...
```

For all three approaches, your module `my_script` would look the same:

**my_script.py**

```
import logging.config
import px_logger

LOGGER = px_logger.getLogger(__name__)

# I used basicConfig here for simplicity, dictConfig should work just as well
logging.basicConfig(level=5,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s [%(filename)s]: %(name)s %(funcName)20s - Message: %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S',
                    filename='myapp.log',
                    filemode='a')

LOGGER.verbose('Test verbose message')
```

Autocomplete works well with all three approaches:

[image: Autocomplete]

Approach two and three have been tested with Python 2.7.15 and 3.6.5 in PyCharm 2018.1 CE

**NOTE:**
In a previous revision of this answer I stated that the docstring approach, although showing the custom `verbose()` method of your PxLogger class, is missing the base class' methods. That is because you derive PxLogger from whatever `logging.getLoggerClass` returns, i.e. an arbitrary class.
If you make PxLogger a subclass of `logging.Logger` explicitly, the type checker knows the base class and can correctly resolve its methods for autocompletion.

I do not recommend subclassing the return value of `getLoggerClass` anyway. You'll want to be sure what you derive from and not rely on a function returning the correct thing.

Answer (score 1):

Annotate the variable with a typing.

```
LOGGER: PxLogger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

**EDIT:**

The solution above works for Python 3.6+. Use `# type: type` comments for previous versions, as noted by @pLOPeGG in comments.

```
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)  # type: PxLogger
```

Comment: Should have mentioned that we are using Python 2.7 and will not be migrating to Python 3 until next year.  Seems variable annotation is 3.6+ feature.

Comment: Can't you use old style annotation with `#type LOGGER: PxLogger` ?

Comment: @JasonTempleman also for Python 3, I would suggest reading [What are Type hints in Python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5) and [Type Hinting in PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html)

Comment: Almost there.  This solution works great for my new added levels but default logger levels are not shown now.  I don't see info, warning, error, etc.  Is it possible to get both?  In not, would adding them to my new levels cause any issues.