# How to give type to argument within function

Tags: python

I am trying to make a function that shortens lists to only 4 elements. However, I am unable to assign a type to the argument of the function, which I have called `my_list`.

I tried using `type()`, but that did not work.

Here is some code:

```
LL = [2,3,4,5,6,2,5,4]
print(len(LL))
def remove_last_elements(the_list):

    the_list.type(list) #Here it gives an error message that I will put below

    for i in range (len(the_list)-4):
        the_list=the_list.remove(the_list[len(the_list)-1])
remove_last_elements(LL)
print(LL)
```

It gives me this error message. If I use `.type()`.

```
    remove_last_elements(LL)
  File "C:\Users\visha\OneDrive\Desktop\Arnav's Things\Coding\Python Programs (and side-products)\Balloons.py", line 5, in remove_last_elements
    the_list.type(list)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'type'
```

Here is another segment of code without the `.type()` thing:

```
LL = [2,3,4,5,6,2,5,4]
print(len(LL))
def remove_last_elements(the_list):
    for i in range (len(the_list)-4):
        the_list=the_list.remove(the_list[len(the_list)-1])
remove_last_elements(LL)
print(LL)
```

Which gives the error message below:

```
  remove_last_elements(LL)
  File "C:\Users\visha\OneDrive\Desktop\Arnav's Things\Coding\Python Programs (and side-products)\Balloons.py", line 5, in remove_last_elements
    the_list=the_list.remove(the_list[len(the_list)-1])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Why do you need to give a type?

Comment: `the_list.remove` will modify it in-place, rather than returning a value, so `the_list` will become `None`

Comment: What about `LL[:4]` or `LL[:-4]` if you want to remove the last four elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LL = [2,3,4,5,6,2,5,4]
print(len(LL))
def remove_last_elements(the_list):
    for i in range (len(the_list)-4):
        the_list=the_list.remove(the_list[len(the_list)-1])
remove_last_elements(LL)
print(LL)
```

you're resetting `the_list` to none, because the_list.remove acts in place, and returns none

try this:

```
LL = [2,3,4,5,6,2,5,4]
print(len(LL))
def remove_last_elements(the_list):
    for i in range (len(the_list)-4):
        the_list.remove(the_list[len(the_list)-1])
remove_last_elements(LL)
print(LL)
```

You cannot set the type of a Python object with `.type()`, you just use `type(x)` to get the type of object `x` is. If you want to change the type of something from, say, a set to a list you could use `list(set('a', 'b'))`

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful, but I still think that your example of code will not work because it will say that you can't use `.remove()` for a `NoneType` object (the_list)

Comment: Okay, let me try again. When I tried it, it gave an error message.

Comment: WHOAH IT WORKED. Thank you again.

Comment: Yeah of course. I would agree with @ggorlen that indexing into your list is a better, and more pythonic way of handling your problem. I fixed the code you had because I thought it would be more informative than telling you to do it a different way.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're attempting to do by "assigning a type to the list". Lists by definition are of type list, which you can validate with `type(the_list)`. I don't recommend making any programmatic decisions based on the result of this, though. Just assume everything is the correct type and crash if it isn't.

If in doubt as to whether a method exists on an object and to see which ones are, you can use `dir()`:

```
>>> dir(list)
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__', '__doc__
', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash_
_', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul_
_', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmu
l__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'append',
 'clear', 'copy', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort'
]
>>> "type" in dir(list)
False
>>>
```

Secondly, `list.remove()` is a function that operates [in place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) and returns the value `None`. when you assign (essentially) `the_list = None`, on the next iteration calling (essentially) `None.remove()` raises the second exception you've encountered.

Resolving these two errors yields:

```
LL = [2,3,4,5,6,2,5,4]

def remove_last_elements(the_list):
    for i in range (len(the_list)-4):
        the_list.remove(the_list[len(the_list)-1])

remove_last_elements(LL)
print(LL)
```

Now, is this function even necessary? I would argue not, for a few reasons.

Firstly, it [hardcodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding) the value 4 without informing the caller, making it almost useless for additional purposes. If I want to remove 5 elements, for example, I'm out of luck and have to write a new function. I would prefer if the shortening size was a parameter to this function so I could specify list shortening of arbitrary `n` values of my own choice.

Secondly, `remove` always removes the first occurrence of an item in the list. Your resulting list, `[2, 3, 6, 2]` is confusing in relation to the service the function name implies "remove last elements". As the user of your function, I'm surprised when two of the last 4 elements in my list are still there!

As a final remark, `.remove` is a very slow operation: for every item in the list, we have to walk up to the entire list to locate and remove it. This will have a serious performance impact on large lists.

I'd use Python's [`slice` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) to perform list shortening efficiently, succinctly and predictably:

```
>>> LL = [2,3,4,5,6,2,5,4]
>>> LL[:-4] # remove and return up to the last 4
[2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> LL[-4:] # remove and return the last 4
[6, 2, 5, 4]
```

You can modify your program to use this as follows:

```
LL = [2,3,4,5,6,2,5,4]

LL = LL[:-4]
print(LL) # => [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Python is dynamically typed. You can't declare the type of a variable like in C or C++. A list is a collection of elements which can have different types. The same list can hold everything: strings, integer, floats, custom classes, etc.

This: `the_list.type(list)` just does not make any sense.

#### EDIT after comments

As said in the comment, It's worth to say that since python 3.5 support for *type hint* is provided. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32558710/10426037) and in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)

Comment: Python is strongly typed. https://www.quora.com/Is-Python-a-truly-strongly-typed-or-a-typeless-language

Comment: @MasonCaiby Thanks for the link. I'll fix my answer

Comment: Thank you. I guess I will just have to change my approach.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I know, but as you said, it's just an hint. But may be worth to mark the point in the answer.