# Is there a python linter that checks types according to type hints?

Tags: python, python-3.x, static-analysis, type-hinting

I'm looking for a Python linter, that can check types usage according to the type hints in the code.
The purpose is to run a single check that verifies style, logic, and type errors.
I need to run this on CI server, and as a file watcher during development.
For example, I need this code to output an error for passing the wrong type argument -

```
def double(x: int):
    return x * 2


result = double('hello')
```

I've checked the documentation of PyLint and flake8, and couldn't find any support for type checking.
With PyLint I also verified there are no errors when checking the above code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are Type hints in Python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5). In particular, see the "Type Hinting with mypy" section -- [mypy](https://mypy-lang.org) is a type checker for Python and was written more or less alongside PEP 484. Two other relatively established type checkers you can maybe also try checking out are [pytype](https://google.github.io/pytype/) and [pyre](https://pyre-check.org).

Comment: Maybe I should make the question clearer. I'm looking for a combination between a linter and a type checker. mypy is only a type checker - it doesn't fail on non-pep8 style, or unused variables etc. I posted this question hoping there is some tool that I can run in CI servers to check the code on both apsects.

Comment: I think the usual strategy is to just run both a linter and the type checker in your CI pipeline as separate programs. I suppose you could look for some sort of plugin that bundles a type checker with your linter (e.g. something like the flake8-mypy plugin), but tbh I don't really see the value in that kind of bundling.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, there is, it's called [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/)

Comment: Is there any way to get mypy to require explicit type annotations? no matter what --disallow's I pass, it's perfectly happy to let me use variables with no type annotation anywhere.

Comment: @MarkReed you can try [strict mode](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-strict)