# Are Python's function argument and return type declarations for show?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm not a Python developer - but am having to use it on a legacy project at work.

**Are Python's function argument and return type declarations just for show?**

```py
# Convert Arrow date objects back to a native datetime object.
def arrow_to_datetime(date: arrow.Arrow) -> datetime:
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(date.timestamp)
```

I can pass any data type in as the date argument and the interpreter doesn't care. It'll still try to access the .timestamp property of whatever is passed as "date".

I can also just return an int even though the declaration says it'll return a datetime, and the interpreter is fine with that too.

What is the point?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are type hints in Python 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5)

Comment: Type hints are purely for IDEs to be able to help you. Python is still dynamically typed. IDEs can give better auto-complete suggestions and can catch errors when using hints, but hints have no effect at runtime. And yes, they are for show. I personally like them because it makes the types explicit, which helps when reading new code.

Comment: Wow. Ok. Php is dynamically typed, but the interpreter still enforces types if you specify them like this. That's where the source of my confusion is. If you shift this to an answer I'll mark it as correct. Thanks.