# What is this Python type hinting syntax, two types enclosed in parenthesis?

Tags: python, pep

I have a method with signature as follows:

```
def get_users_for_survey(survey_id: (int, str),show_deleted_users: bool = False) -> list:
    pass
```

I have avoided the method body because I am only interested in the type hinting part for survey_id? Looks like it means it could be either int or str. I thought if that was the intention then it should have been survey_id: Union(int,str). PyCharm is not objecting. Do you think I missed something in PEP 484? I do not think it was meant to be a tuple.

**Edit** As per answers provided here, this is just a mistake. Now I know what is the origin of this mistake.
In the same method next line was:

```
if survey_id and isinstance(survey_id, (int, str)):
```

So you see in isinstance if you want to accommodate for multiple types this is a valid syntax. Author of this method thought this is a valid syntax for type hinting as well.Here is a reference:
[Python isinstance with multiple types](https://pynative.com/python-isinstance-explained-with-examples/)

Comment: Contrary to common expectation, Python's "type hints" are just *annotations*. They can be literally anything. They mean whatever you want them to mean. Meaning: it doesn't have to be "valid" in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're right this isn't a valid TypeHint syntax, the valid type hint syntax according to the **PEP484** would be

```
from typing import Union

def get_users_for_survey(survey_id: Union[int, str],show_deleted_users: bool = False) -> list:
    pass
```

which means the **survey_id** either be of type **int or str**.

The second question you asked is **"Why PyCharm not complaining about it.?"** 
 
**Ans:**

> Rather treating it as an invalid TypeHint, the PyCharm treats it as
>   type **None** which is equivalent to TypeHint **Any** means it may be of any type.

Even if you use this syntax for type hint(which is not valid at all)

```
def get_users_for_survey(survey_id: int or str, show_deleted_users: bool = False) -> list:
    pass
```

still, there will be no warning or errors.

Answer (score 0):

In short, python type hinting is exactly what it says it is. Type ***hinting***. Python does not check types, however they are good for a couple things:

1. They help type-checkers
2. They help with creating documentation

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32558710/9699953 (READ THIS! This is about type-hinting (what it is, how to use it)).

Answer (score -2):

Python "type hints" aren't actually implemented as such, they're just *annotations*. You can literally *annotate* your functions and parameters with arbitrary stuff:

```
>>> def foo(bar: (int, str)): pass
>>> foo.__annotations__
{'bar': (<class 'int'>, <class 'str'>)}
```

This can mean whatever you want it to mean, and you can use it for arbitrary purposes. Python itself doesn't do anything with it.

I believe the type hint `(int, str)` is merely meaningless, so type checkers like PyCharm simply don't complain about it.