# Typing: How to pass class as a parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I am trying to pass a class to a function in Python and then instantiate it in the function and return it.
This works so far, but as soon as I try to add the Python types I get the following error:

```
Expected no arguments to "object" constructor Pylance (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

Here is a minimal example where the error occurs.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Dict, Type, TypeVar

@dataclass
class Bar:
    x: int

T = TypeVar('T')

def Foo(clazz: Type[T], kwargs: Dict[str, int]) -> T:
    return clazz(**kwargs)  # --> Expected no arguments to "object" constructor

bar = Foo(Bar, {'x': 1})
print(type(bar))  # --> <class '__main__.Bar'>
```

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: In short, the annotation claims this works for all types and all arguments, when in fact it clearly does not.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thank you for the explanation. That makes sense. Can you give me a hint on what I would need to adjust to make it work?

Comment: Do you have any restrictions on the type?

Comment: I believe you should be defining Foo as: `def Foo(clazz: Type, kwargs: Dict[str, int]) -> T: ...` . Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60457872/286807

Answer (score 0):

It can be made to work with  cast, explicitly telling the
typechecker that clazz is a subtype of object
that can accept named arguments. (there may be
a better casting target than `Any` for that,
but this works)

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Dict, Type, TypeVar, Any, cast

@dataclass
class Bar:
    x: int

T = TypeVar('T')


def Foo(clazz: Type[T], kwargs: Dict[str, int]) -> T:
    clazz = cast(Type[Any], clazz)
    return clazz(**kwargs)  # --> Expected no arguments to "object" constructor

bar = Foo(Bar, {'x': 1})
print(type(bar))
```