# Reading shoe size from user input does not work

Tags: python

The problem is that I create a variant (let's say `lemon_number = 5`) and I want to multiply it by the age of the person (that I asked with `input()`). I tried `int`, `str` and didn't find anything.

There's the code:

```
print("Hi. Today we will calculate your age with your shoes size.")
response1 = input("Are you ready ? (1 = yes, 2 = no) ")
no = 2
yes = 1
if response1 == str(no):
    print("ok")
elif response1 == str(yes):
    five: int = 5
    shoes_size = input("Good ! So firstly tell me your shoes size : ")
    print("Now, we have to multiplie it by 5. It gives " + ((str)(shoes_size)*(int)(five)))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What do you think the expression `(str)(shoes_size)*(int)(five)` evaluates to? Do you know what `"fred" * 5` evaluates to? Also note that `(var1)(var2)` simply evaluates as `var1(var2)`. There are no casts in Python, only function calls.

Comment: Since this is python. try executing this line by line in a python console. You will find it useful to see what each line does. You can open a python console by typing python in your terminal. Or use an online python console.

Comment: Python does not have C-style casts. `int` is a function, so write `int(shoes_size)` to convert it to an int.

Comment: This style is C++ I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the final call to `print` with:

```
print("Now, we have to multiplie it by 5. It gives " + str(int(shoes_size)*five))
```

Your output will then become

```
Good ! So firstly tell me your shoes size : 2
Now, we have to multiplie it by 5. It gives 10
```

Note that the result is 10 now.

You need to convert input into integer `int(shoes_size)`, do calculation (multiplication) and the result convert to `str` before concatenating it with string.

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Thanks. Hope it'll be me helping you one day :D

Answer (score 1):

You seemed to be in the correct direction. The problem is that in the last print statement you are multiplying a string by an int.

The way string multiplication works in python is that if we multiple 'a' by 3 you will get this result:

```
'a' * 3
>>>'aaa'
```

The answer to your problem would be to cast shoe size to an int and then cast the result to a string.

```
print("Now, we have to multiplie it by 5. It gives " + str(((int)(shoes_size)*(int)(five))))
```

This isn't the ideal way to do it, but it will work for your problem

Comment: Hello! As noted in the top level comments, there is no such thing as a "cast" in Python. The syntax in your second snippet is rather misleading for beginners. It's also rather meaningless to call the builtin `int` on an existing integer object.

Comment: @Brian I think you are correct. However I did want to give an answer the resembled the user code as close as possible. I did note in my solution that it is not the ideal way to go about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
response1 = int(input("Are you ready ? (1 = yes, 2 = no) "))
if response1 == 2:
    print("ok")
elif response1 == 1:
    shoe_size =int(input("Good ! So firstly tell me your shoes size : "))
    print("Now, we have to multiplie it by 5. It gives " + shoe_size*5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late here, but this one just adds some short explanations and links for some edits.

```
print("Hi. Today we will calculate your age with your shoes size.")
response1 = input("Are you ready ? (1 = yes, 2 = no)")

#Using variables that are only used once is generally not a good idea.
#(Code in question: no = 2, yes = 1)
if response1 == "2":
    print("ok")
elif response1 == "1":
    # Code I am talking about: five: int = 5
    #(There is no need to hint whether a variable in python is an integer or a string). The type hint (five :int) is used when you want others reading your code to understand how it works(like if you are a developer/module publisher).
# ^ see my link at the end for more information on type hints
    #Also, "five" was only used once. The purpose of variables is to be reused.
    shoes_size = input("Good ! So firstly tell me your shoes size : ")
    #The way you convert something's type is by calling int(something).
    print("Now, we have to multiply it by 5. It gives " + int(shoes_size)*5)
```

TL;DR:
Don't use "only-use" variables. For example, if you want to `print(1)`, don't

```
a = 1
print(a)
```

The simplest way to convert the type of something is by calling `int(something)`,`str(something)`,`float(something)`,etc. not (int)(something)`
Saves you a pair of parentheses, and makes the code simpler.
Finally, multiplying a string by a number repeats it that many times. The full list of interactions is visible at [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex), but be warned, it is the docs, so it is pretty technical.

[link about type hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5)

Comment: thanks much :D And I complicate things because i'm just learning and these are exercices. So I do things to learn more but, you explained well, thanks ^^