# (Python) Why does running the line "wut:2+2=5" not give a syntax error?

Tags: python-3.x

Why is code like this apparently legal (does not give a syntax error when running) in Python 3?

```
wut:2+2=5
```

I've tried to find out what this type of syntax could mean and I could not find it. It seems like a key-value pair, but can you just have one lying around? And "2+2=5" is not a valid... anything, is it?

Comment: [Type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html): it treats `2+2` as a type hint, even though it appears to be meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are **type hints** in python. Basically, you hint the type of the object(s) you're using. Type-hints are for maintainability and don't get interpreted by Python. So, you might say that a variable has type float whereas python will internally interpret as int only. Eg -

```
my_var:float = 4
print(type(my_var))
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
<class 'int'>
```

In your case, it doesn't make much sense. But to ease maintainability when your projects grow large, it is helpful. These can be considered as the next step from # type comments. Eg-

1. ```
   my_var = 4.2  # type: float
   ```
2. ```
   my_var: float = 4.2
   ```

The above two codes can be considered to be similar in their functionalities.

You can read more about it here - https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

More on this - [What are type hints in Python 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5)