# Type defining in function args?

Tags: python

What's this?

```
def sqr(v:int):
    return v*v
```

It looks like type restriction, so this function takes just int values, but it doesn't. Is it just a decoration for debuggers?

Comment: This is known as type hinting. You can read more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5

Comment: Hi, thanks for the question. If my answer solves your problem, you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Explain this language feature" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the **type hinting**. It is not a restriction, it's a helper for other developers, most linters as `mypy` and PyCharm linter also use this to prevent type errors. This feature is optional for using, but it helps you write more clean and testable code.