# What is the meaning of set[...] in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, set

I'm pretty new to programming and python.

As far as I know, for the initialization of the set function you use `set()` for an empty set, and `{ ... }` to initialize elements as a set. In an example code, I saw `set[X]`. What is the meaning of the square brackets used in set?

This is the example code:

```
def example_function(x: set[A], y: set[B]) -> set[tuple[A, B]]:
    res = set()
    for i in x:
        for j in y:
            res.add((i, j))
    return res
```

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/

Comment: You may also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [type hint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), in this example, we use type hint For collections, the type of the collection item is in brackets.

## Example:

```
# Python 3.9
# For collections, the type of the collection item is in brackets
int_list: list[int] = [1]
int_set: set[int] = {6, 7}

# Python 3.8 and earlier, the name of the collection type is
# capitalized, and the type is imported from 'typing'

from typing import List, Set, Dict, Tuple, Optional

int_list: List[int] = [1]
int_set: Set[int] = {6, 7}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a parameterising the functions and variable annotations to say that the function needs two arguments, namely `x` and `y` which are of type `set`(build from A and B respectively) and it returns back a set consisting of tuples built by mixing `set[A]` `set[B]`