# Simple question about python function type annotation&hint

Tags: python, mypy

Suppose there is a function written in Python

```
def functionname() -> int:
```

Should the programmer must return the `int` in this function? Or is it acceptable to return nothing but use `print()`?
Should the programmer must return the same data type as the type hint?

Comment: "Should" and "must" typically have different meanings (especially in computing, see e.g. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2119). Why do you think it would be acceptable to not return an int from a function whose return type annotation says it returns an int?

Comment: I thought it is acceptable to not follow type annotation. Isn't type annotation optional?  It is allowed to return nothing or print when the annotation is int.

Comment: If you're not going to follow it, why bother including it at all? It's not enforced by the interpreter, but e.g. MyPy won't like it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are type hints in Python 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not **necessary** to return an `int`, as in there won't be any error raised if you won't return an `int`, but if you do not want to return anything or just call a `print` in the function, it is better to annotate the return type as `None` and not `int`.

Edit: If you want it to return `None` *or* an `int`, then you can typehint it as [`typing.Union[None, int]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) or [`typehint.Optional[int]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional)