# Meaning of colon in function Init signature

Tags: python, pandas, series

I am looking at the Init signature of `pd.Series`. It is as follows:

```
pd.Series(
    data=None,
    index=None,
    dtype: 'Dtype | None' = None,
    name=None,
    copy: 'bool' = False,
    fastpath: 'bool' = False,
)
```

Please could somebody explain why it says `dtype: 'Dtype | None' = None` and not simply `dtype = None`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are type hints in Python 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5) Specifically, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38045620/3000206) answer.

Comment: On top of that, `|` is the new symbol for `typing.Union`. That type hint would also be written as `typing.Optional[Dtype]`.