# Why is the code in my function is displaying in white text in VSCode

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Unlike other methods used in different parts of the function in my program, the methods used in this part of the function is plain white and it says "method name: Any". For example, `.isupper()` shows `isupper: Any` whereas `.lower()` displays a different one.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `symbol` is not explicitly stated to be of type `str`, which `isupper()` and `islower()` are methods of. In `ascii_letters`, I imagine you have explicitly stated `str` types as values/elements, which is why vscode properly recognizes `ascii_letters[key_position]` to be of type `str` and thus why the `lower()` method is properly highlighted and described.

To remove the ambiguity, you could introduce [type hinting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html):

```
def check_text_case(symbol: str, result: list, key_position: int) -> None:
    if symbol.isupper():
        result.append(ascii_letters[key_position])
    elif symbol.islower():
        result.append(ascii_letters[key_position].lower())
```

This way, the types are explicitly stated and the code is properly highlighted and described.

Comment: I see, I have one question. In the doc where you linked the "typing', it also uses "-> None", what exactly is the usage here because I'm still confused after reading the doc.

Comment: The `-> None` refers to the `return` type of the function. In your case, there is no `return` statement, but the function implicitly returns `None`. Here are some nice articles on the subject: https://realpython.com/lessons/type-hinting/#:~:text=Type%20hinting%20is%20a%20formal,type%20information%20to%20a%20function, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5