# the function that takes an array of size n as its arguments and return the number of array elements which are equal to their index value in array

Tags: python

Below is my code and I'm getting a snytax error at def. Please can anyone help with answer?

```
def ElementsandIndices(int [] arr, int n):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, n):
        if arr[i] == i:
            count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: there is no  `int [] arr` syntax in python, thats in java.

Comment: Before asking any questions, you should read a basic Python tutorial.

Comment: "I'm getting a snytax error at def" See how there's a `^` symbol in the error message? Notice where it's pointing?

Comment: Thank you. Actually I didn't notice the syntax of array. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Python is not a strong-typed language, and you have your definitions a little mixed up.
Since, by default, variables do not have a type, here's the normal way to define this function:

```py
def ElementsandIndices(arr, n):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, n):
        if arr[i] == i:
            count += 1
    return count
```

However, recently typing has become optional, as an additional context assistant to whatever IDE you're using. So if you want to see the types, you can define it like so in Python 3.7+

```py
from typing import List

def ElementsandIndices(arr:List[int], n:int):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, n):
        if arr[i] == i:
            count += 1
    return count
```

If your Python version is Python 3.9+, you can use `list` instead of `typing.List`:

```py
def ElementsandIndices(arr:list[int], n:int):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, n):
        if arr[i] == i:
            count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: The version is Python 3.9+

Comment: @AlanBagel Type hinting was introduced in Python 3.7

Comment: I know, but the `<builtin_date_type>[<something>]` was introduced in Python 3.9. (example: list[int])

Comment: The version when type hints were introduced was Python 3.5, but the generic builtin data type hinting was introduced in Python 3.9.

Answer (score 0):

`int [] arr` and `int n` are both not valid python syntax. Just use `arr` and `n` instead. If you want to specify the argument's type, use [type hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5).

Comment: Yeah sure I'll use

Answer (score -1):

It can be done in 1 line

```
def ElementsandIndices(arr):
    return sum(1 for i,v in enumerate(arr) if v == i)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question was saying that there was an syntax error.

Comment: @AlanBagel Where in the question title do you see the words `syntax error`

Comment: He/she said it was a `snytax error` but it was probably a typo. (syntax error)