# Use Python typing for two types

Tags: python, python-typing

I am using a simplified example, to show the problem. I have a function, could also be a method, which should accept only `int` or `bool`
Any other type should be removed. I know how to input one type, I don't know how to input both. I have tried `Sequence` from the `typing`, but failed.See code below:

```
int_bool = TypeVar( "int_bool", int, bool)
def foo( a : Sequence[ int_bool ] ):
    print( a )
foo( 1.1 )
>>> 1.1
```

It should error out, as 1.1 is neither `int` nor `bool`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are type hints in Python 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I have made a mistake. Unlike some other languages (Cadence SKILL++ comes to mind), this functionality is for documentation, and hinting, and has no enforcement mechanism.
i.e., it's doing what it is supposed to do, not what I wanted it to do, or thought that it was supposed to do.

Comment: The closest you can get is to use a static checker like mypy. You can run it as a pre-commit or as a test or before running your app. Of course, it's a _static_ checker, so if the value is only defined during runtime, then it still won't catch the error.

Comment: The idea is a dynamic one, as in Cadence  SKILL++