# What does "a: 5" without curly braces mean?

Tags: python, syntax

I noticed that if I type, for instance `>>> a: 5` as input of the python interpreter, it does not return an error (whether or not the variable 'a' is already defined). However, if I type `>>> a` afterwards, I get the usual NameError.

My question is: what does the python interpreter do when I type this kind of dictionary syntax without the curly braces?

Originally, I found this syntax in matplotlib's matplotlibrc file (see [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html)).

Answer (score 1):

It defines a type hint. But without a value, the variable will not be initialized in the global scope.

```py
>>> a: int = 3
>>> globals()['__annotations__']
{'a': <class 'int'>}
>>> a
3

>>> b: str
>>> globals()['__annotations__']
{'a': <class 'int'>, 'b': <class 'str'>}
>>> b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

`a: 5` in the interpreter uses the [type hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5) syntax, but this has nothing to do with what you see in matplotlib's documentation that defines a **configuration file** (and thus is not python code).

from the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#defining-your-own-style):

> You can create custom styles and use them by calling style.use with the path or URL to the style sheet.
>
> For example, you might want to create ./images/presentation.mplstyle with the following:

```
axes.titlesize : 24
axes.labelsize : 20
lines.linewidth : 3
lines.markersize : 10
xtick.labelsize : 16
ytick.labelsize : 16
```

The above is **not** python code