# What does '->' in function definition/declaration stmt in python means?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

The function I saw has a "->int" sign after the declaration statement.

```
class Solution:
    def numUniqueEmails(self, emails: List[str]) -> int:
```

What does it mean? And how can it be used or the best practices to follow?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5