# Python3 OOPS .. How would i call this class in the same python file and what does the syntax of the function head mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, oop

```
class Solution:
    def romanToInt(self, s: str) -> int:
       dict = {
        'I' : 1,
        'V' : 5,
        'X' : 10,
        'L' : 50,
        'C' : 100,
        'D' : 500,
        'M' : 1000
        } 
       result  = 0
       tmp = 0;
       i = 0

       while i < len(s):
           tmp = dict[s[i]];
           if (i +1) < len(s) and dict[s[i]] < dict[s[i + 1]]:
               tmp = dict[s[i + 1]] - dict[s[i]]
               i += 1
           i += 1
           result += tmp;

       print (result)
```

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5) help at all?

Comment: `Solution().romanToInt("V")`; `romanToInt(self, s: str) -> int:` - `:str` and `-> int` are **type hints** - they do not have an effect on the behaviour of the function, but can be used by IDE to suggest how the method is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code a little bit because you shouldn't use type keywords as variable names and to make it more readable

```
class Solution:

    def romanToInt(self, text: str) -> int:
       pairs = {
        'I' : 1, 'V' : 5, 'X' : 10, 'L' : 50,
        'C' : 100, 'D' : 500, 'M' : 1000 
       } 
       result = tmp = i = 0
       while i < len(text):
           tmp = pairs[text[i]];
           if i + 1 < len(text) and pairs[text[i]] < pairs[text[i + 1]]:
               tmp = pairs[text[i + 1]] - pairs[text[i]]
               i += 1
           i += 1
           result += tmp
       print(result)


solution = Solution()          # initialize instance of Solution class
solution.romanToInt("XXVIII")  # run the romanToInt method
```

ouput = `28`