# Can anyone explain (def equalFrequency(self, word: str) -> bool:) this python function?

Tags: python, function, class

this is the full code:

```
class Solution:
    def equalFrequency(self, word: str) -> bool:
```

I want to know what is word:str -> bool: means in python

Can anyone explain this with examples. I only want to know what is word: str -> bool: means in python.

Comment: Those are annotations that tell things like linters what should be passed to a function and what it will return. They may also help people figure out how to use a function. Because nobody can write a doc string I guess?? They don't have any affect on the code itself. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/annotations.html

Comment: See better canonical Q&A: [What are type hints in Python 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32557920/2745495)

Comment: You are actually asking about 2 separate things: the type hint for `word: str` and the type hint for the return value `-> bool`. It's not one `word:str -> bool`. But they both fall under the search term "type hints" or "type annotations", which the links above already explain.

Answer (score 0):

This is python typing.

`word: str` says that the argument `word` is expected to be of type `str` (string)

`def equalFrequency(self, word: str) -> bool` says that function `equalFrequency` is expected to return a `bool` (boolean), so we should get a true or false values from the function

**Examples:**

`equalFrequency('hello')` ==> Correct

`equalFrequency(123)` ==> Incorrect

Correct:

```py
class Solution:
    def equalFrequency(self, word: str) -> bool:
        return true
```

Incorrect:

```py
class Solution:
    def equalFrequency(self, word: str) -> bool:
        return 123
```

Comment: But to be clear, python is dynamic and doesn't have typing. They are type hints for people and linters.

Comment: `equalFrequency(123) ==> Incorrect` : Unless you are using a linter like mypy, Python will not actually raise an error on that code, and will happily go along and assign the int 123 to `word`. Same as for the return value.