# does pydev support python 3.5 Type Hints?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I use eclipse/pydev.

I recently learned about python 3.5 support for type hints https://medium.com/techtofreedom/8-levels-of-using-type-hints-in-python-a6717e28f8fd

I found https://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_type_hints.html. It looks like type support is done using sphinx and epydoc.

Does anyone know of plans to support the python native type hint mechanism?

Kind regards

Andy

Comment: Type hints were introduced in Python 3.5.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5

Comment: I would strongly suggest moving on to a more recent minor version - Python 3.5 and 3.6 [have reached end of life](https://devguide.python.org/versions/).  If possible, I would suggest trying to update to 3.10 or 3.11.

Answer (score 0):

PyDev does support type hints in its type-inference engine and uses it internally.

If you have any issue related, please report it at:

https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev/

p.s.: latest versions of PyDev only support Python 3.6 onwards (but type hint support has actually been available for a long time already).

p.s.2: PyDev uses it internally for its type inference, but it won't show errors. You have to use the mypy integration for typing errors to appear.