# Can someone please help me understand what this colon is doing here?

Tags: python

I saw a video that used a colon in an unusual way in Python, but replicating the operation in Jupyter, I can't figure out what is happening:

```
x=0
i: x=9

print(i)
print(x)
```

I get:

```
9
0
```

What is actually happening here with i and x, and what is the underlying operation here?

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5) help at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an (invalid) [type hint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).

To be correct, it *should* be:

```py
i: int = 9
```

But type hints don't affect normal execution, so you don't see the program behave differently.