# _text_replacement_pattern: "re.Pattern[str]" = re.compile(r"\{(" + inner_pattern + r")\}")

Tags: python-re

Could anyone please help me understand the difference of the following two functions? Thanks!

```
def my_format_1(template: str, **kwargs: Callable[[], str]) -> str:
    inner_pattern = "|".join(kwargs.keys())
    pattern = re.compile(r"\{(" + inner_pattern + r")\}")

    def repl(match: "re.Match[str]") -> str:
        key = match.group(1).upper()
        if f := kwargs.get(key):
            return f()
        else:
            return match.group(0)

    return pattern.sub(repl, template)
```

---

```
def my_format_2(template: str, **kwargs: Callable[[], str]) -> str:
    inner_pattern = "|".join(kwargs.keys())
    _text_replacement_pattern: "re.Pattern[str]" = re.compile(r"\{(" + inner_pattern + r")\}")

    def repl(match: "re.Match[str]") -> str:
        key = match.group(1).upper()
        if f := kwargs.get(key):
            return f()
        else:
            return match.group(0)

    return _text_replacement_pattern.sub(repl, template)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are type hints in Python 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5)

Answer (score -1):

The overall structure and purpose of the `my_format_2` function is the same as `my_format_1`.

The main difference between the two functions is in the naming and type hinting:

- In `my_format_2`, the regular expression pattern is stored in a variable named `_text_replacement_pattern`, and it's type hint is explicitly specified as `re.Pattern[str]`.
- In `my_format_1`, the pattern variable is simply named `pattern`, and it's type hint is not explicitly specified.

Overall, both functions `my_format_1` and `my_format_2` perform similar tasks, but `my_format_2` provides more explicit naming and type hinting for the regular expression pattern. The core logic for formatting the string remains the same between the two functions.