# Why doesn't Python 3.11 throw an error at print(set[0])?

Tags: python, printing, set

I accidentally came across a very strange behavior for the later versions of Python. `print(set[0])` will actually print `set[0]` instead of throwing an error in Python 3.9 and higher. Older versions of Python did not allow such behavior. Does anyone have any insight into why this works? I don't think I will be able to sleep tonight!

I expected to get a TypeError exception saying that a set is not subscriptable.

Comment: My guess is that it is allowed due to [type hinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5)

Comment: Indeed. Notice that `type(set[0])` gives `<class 'types.GenericAlias'>`.

Comment: Are you talking about a built-in `set` object that you have named `set`, or are you talking about the built-in `set` name itself? If you have a set named `a`, and you run `a[0]`, you'll get the "not subscriptable" error. But if you literally are doing this to the name `set`, then yeah, you're doing type hinting, which is certainly not what you intended.

Comment: I'm talking about the built-in ```set``` data type.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [type alias](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases) used for type hinting

```
>>> x=set[0]
>>> type(x)
<class 'types.GenericAlias'>
```

It doesn't make much sense as the expression between brackets is supposed to be a type ex `list[float]` but syntax is correct

Answer (score 1):

The feature was introduced in [PEP 585 – Type Hinting Generics In Standard Collections](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/). It is available since Python 3.7 by importing `from __future__ import annotations`. Note that you can get the generic type parameters using `set[0].__args__`. Example:

```py
>>> set[0,1].__args__
(0, 1)
```

The feature allows passing in literal values as type parameters, although that use case is not documented in PEP 585, and some type checkers may even take issue with it.