# Type checking best practice

Tags: python, typechecking

## Problem

Imagine I have a base class, e.g. `TreeNode` with several subclasses
deriving from it, possibly with more instance fields (like children for inner nodes). What are current best practices to check against the
concrete class Type. I may have something like `NumericNode` and `CharacterNode` and a function that accepts both.

## Solutions

One possibility would be of course to use `isinstance()` but I
think this is rather unpythonic. Another solution (which I would
like to avoid as much as possible) is to use something like a class
constant per subclass and then check against it. This would be similar to the first solution.
Or should I encapsulate the isinstance() solution into a dedicated function that hides the real typechecking?

Comment: Why does your function need to care which it gets? Python generally used *"duck typing"*, relying on the *interface* to be correct (assuming it is and throwing an error if it isn't) rather than explicit, up-front checking of types.

Comment: Seems like you're designing your classes wrong. It sounds like you need common method names with each subclass overriding to implement however is appropriate for that type.

Comment: if you really want to enforce the type without lots of explicit checking in your function you could always use [this recipe for enforcing types in annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21806460/5827215)